# Convexity with setting $ \lambda=\frac{1}{2}$ implies continuity?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

I'm not sure if there is already an answer to this particular question, but here it goes,

(Definition of convexity that is used here: 
Let $D \subset \mathbb{R}$ be an (infinite or finite) interval. A function $f:D\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is called convex if for any $x_1,x_2 \in D$ and any $\lambda$ with $0<\lambda<1$,

$$f(\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2)\leq \lambda f(x_1) + (1-\lambda) f(x_2)$$
is valid
)

The following was already proven:

In an interval $I \subset S $ continuous function $f:I \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ 
is then convex if and only if

$(1)$
$$f\bigg(\frac{x+y}{2}\bigg)\leq\frac{f(x)+f(y)}{2} $$
for any $x,y \in I$.

In the proof, the ( -> ) part is almost direct by setting $\lambda=\frac{1}{2}$ into the definition of convexity. But as for ( <- ) I had to use the continuous property of the function, but I wonder if the property $(1)$ stated above actually implies continuity so that the theorem above doesn't need to state the continuity property, as of:

In an interval $I \subset S $ function $f:I \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ 
is then convex if and only if

$(1)$
$$f\bigg(\frac{x+y}{2}\bigg)\leq\frac{f(x)+f(y)}{2} $$
for any $x,y \in I$.

I tried also to find counterexamples but to no avail, as it is for me rather intuitive that the property $(1)$ should imply continuity but I'm not sure, maybe the proof can be similar to the proof of "convexity implies continuity". I would love to see some counterexamples (assuming they exist) or perhaps the proof.
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Is $I$ an open interval?

Comment: You need extra conditions such as measurability, see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/83383/27978.

Comment: I think it doesn't have to be open. But will being an open interval help?

Comment: @copper.hat Ah I see, but do you know any counterexamples for this?

Comment: @hteica: I'm not sure what you mean? There is a non measurable example of a mid point convex function that is not convex (uses Axiom of choice).

Comment: The definition suggested in (1) is known as J-convex which includes 'regular convexity' but is not the same thing as it.  (As I recall J-convexity is the criterion original suggested by Jensen, but things have moved away from that.)

Comment: @copper.hat I'm sorry, do you mind to explain a bit about the counterexample, which uses the Axiom of choice? Thanks.

Comment: @user8675309 What do you mean by regular convexity?

Comment: I mean the modern definition.  You overloaded (1) in your definitions in your post... I meant J-convex for the second (1) and modern /regular convex for the first (1)

Comment: Look at Martin's answer in the link I added https://math.stackexchange.com/a/83398/27978..

Comment: @user8675309 I still don't get what you mean, sorry. But the second (1) was not true right? since we need the continuity property or the measurability (as stated by copper.hat in the comment above)

Comment: @copper.hat ah I see, thank you

Comment: the second (1) is called J-convexity *not* convexity

Comment: @user8675309 I see, so this means that J-convexity does not imply convexity?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/302684/weak-convexity-and-continuity?rq=1